# Is it possible to wrap up python binary installers into a single package?

Tags: python

I distribute a software package that is dependent on a variety of binary python extension modules.  Sometimes at conferences we have participants install these packages so we can demo how to script our software tool.  It's a pain to have folks click through 12 different installers.  Is it possible to take existing python binary extension modules and build them into a single installer that will install all 12 at once?

If relevant, here are the python modules I'd like to wrap up:

- Cython
- Numpy Superpack
- GDAL
- PIL
- py2exe
- PyQt
- Scipy Superpack
- Setuptools
- Distribute
- Nose
- Shapely
- PyAMG
- Virtualenv
- Poster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via pip. You can write a simple python script the will install all these from a requirements text file.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirements-file-format

Or to cut down on the time and I see you have numpy in your list you will most likely need to use the wheels packages.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could write a script (doesn't have to be python) that uses pip or alike to install all those libraries. If you do that, be carefull with dependencies and the order in which you install those libraries.

You could also download all of the libraries and then call all the setup.py files instead of using pip.